# Prove that $\sin(nx) \cos((n+1)x)-\sin((n-1)x)\cos(nx) = \sin(x) \cos(2nx)$

Tags: trigonometry

**Question:**
Prove that $\sin(nx) \cos((n+1)x)-\sin((n-1)x)\cos(nx) = \sin(x) \cos(2nx)$ for $n \in \mathbb{R}$.

**My attempts:**

> I initially began messing around with the product to sum identities, but I couldn't find any way to actually use them.
> I also tried compound angles to expand the expression, but it became too difficult to work with.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I always find that using $2\cos x=e^{ix}+e^{-ix}$ and $2i\sin x=e^{ix}-e^{-ix}$ makes these calculations routine.

Comment: I guess this implies an identity of Chebyshev polynomials $Q_n(x) P_{n+1}(x) - Q_{n-1}(x) P_n(x) = P_{2n}(x)$.  Just to go completely off on a tangent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left-hand side is$$\begin{align}&\sin nx(\cos nx\cos x-\sin nx\sin x)-(\sin nx\cos x-\cos nx\sin x)\cos nx\\&=(\cos^2nx-\sin^2nx)\sin x\\&=\cos 2nx\sin x.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use $\sin(a)\cos(b)=\frac{1}{2}(\sin(a-b)+\sin(a+b))$:
$$
\sin(nx) \cos((n+1)x)-\sin((n-1)x)\cos(nx) 
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(-x)+\sin((2n+1)x)-\sin(-x)-\sin((2n-1)x) \right)
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin((2n+1)x)-\sin((2n-1)x) \right)
$$Now use $\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\sin(b)\cos(a)$:
$$
=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(2nx)\cos(x)
+\sin(x)\cos(2nx)-\sin(2nx)\cos(-x)-\sin(-x)\cos(2nx) \right)
$$Now use the parity of sine and cosine and you're done.
$$
=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(2nx)\cos(x)
+\sin(x)\cos(2nx)-\sin(2nx)\cos(x)+\sin(x)\cos(2nx) \right)
$$
$$
=\sin(x)\cos(2nx)
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
\sin(nx)\cos((n+1)x)
&=\frac{\sin(nx+(n+1)x)+\sin(nx-(n+1)x)}2\tag1\\
&=\frac{\sin((2n+1)x)-\sin(x)}2\tag2\\
\sin((n-1)x)\cos(nx)
&=\frac{\sin((2n-1)x)-\sin(x)}2\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: identity: $\sin(a)\cos(b)=\frac{\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b)}2$
$(2)$: simplify
$(3)$: apply $(2)$ for $n-1$

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(nx)\cos((n+1)x)-\sin((n-1)x)\cos(nx)
&=\frac{\sin((2n+1)x)-\sin((2n-1)x)}2\tag4\\
&=\sin(x)\cos(2nx)\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(4)$: subtract $(3)$ from $(2)$
$(5)$: identity: $\sin(a)-\sin(b)=2\sin\left(\frac{a-b}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)$